# Is there a more efficient way to process this data?

Tags: python, django

I have a bunch of data points in the format `(x, y, z, a, b, c)` where `x` is an integer, `y` is a date, `z` is an integer, and `a`, `b`, and `c` are different numerical values (integers and floats).

My goal is to allow the user to provide two dates (so two `y` values), and then be presented with the values of `(delta_a, delta_b, delta_c)` for all existing `(x, z)` values; `delta_a` would be the increase/decrease in the value of `a` between the two dates, etc.

For example, let's say there's just 3 possible values of `x` and 3 possible values of `z`. The user provides two dates, `y1=date(2023,2,7)` and `y2=date(2023,2,15)` This data is presented in a table, like this:

[image: example data]

Now in reality, there's about 30 different values of `x` and about 400 different values of `z`, so this table would actually have about 30 rows and about 400 columns (I have a horizontal scrollbar inside the table to look through the data).

Also, the value of `y` can be any date (at least since I started importing this data, about a month ago). So every day, about 12,000 new data entries are added to the database.

The way I'm currently handling this is I have a model `DataEntry` which basically looks like this:

```
class DataEntry(models.Model):
    x = models.IntegerField()
    y = models.DateField()
    z = models.IntegerField()
    a = models.IntegerField()
    b = models.FloatField()
    c = models.FloatField()
```

So every time the user generates a data table by inputting two dates, it can take quite a while since the system is comparing the ~12,000 data entries for `y1` with the ~12,000 data entries for `y2` and displaying all the different values. I will say that not every `z` value is actually displayed, because the user also inputs a minimum `delta_a` value, which is 5 by default - so if `a` did not increase by at least 5, then that table cell is empty. And if an entire column is just empty data cells, i.e. there's no `x` value for that given `z` column which had an `a` value increase by at least 5, then the column is hidden. So sometimes there's as few as 20 columns actually showing, but sometimes there's closer to 100. The user can choose to display all data though, meaning the full ~400 columns.

I hope I've explained this sufficiently. Is there a more efficient way to be handling all this? Does it actually make sense to have distinct objects for every single data entry or is there some way I could condense this down to maybe speed up the process?

Any pointers?

Comment: What is more expensive, the comparison calculations or the database query?

Comment: not sure.. how could I figure that out?

Comment: Are you doing the delta calculations in python or in the database?

Comment: try https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ or https://pypi.org/project/django-query-profiler/

Comment: @BradyDean I am doing them in python

Comment: This calculation could be done in the database, but it's not really something Django excells at letting you do unfortunently. Maybe try putting the data into numpy/pandas and see if that gives you good enough performance, otherwise you might have to write some sql. Someone may prove me wrong about Django tho.

Comment: You basically need to join this table on itself right? One query for each date, then join on a.x=b.x and a.z=b.z, then have 3 computed columns. Django just doesn't let you do joins like that